# utf8 torrent files

Tags: bittorrent, utf-8

I have a [CinemaGo HD media player](http://www.brite-view.com/cinemago.php), that has a built-in torrent client (I guess it is bit-torrent). But I am unable to download some torrent files because they are not in utf-8 format (you can see it by looking at the torrent file header).

Is there any way of converting a .torrent file to utf-8 (maybe by re-encoding it)?